# How to set a time and day to continue executing a python program

Tags: python, email

Code below:

```
import smtplib
content = ["zero","one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"]

def email (content):    
    FROMADDR = "SENDER@gmail.com"
    LOGIN    = FROMADDR 
    PASSWORD = "PASSWORD"
    TOADDRS  = ["SEND TO"]
    SUBJECT  = "Test"
    for term in content: #LOOP
        msg = ("From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\nSubject: %s\r\n\r\n"
               % (FROMADDR, ", ".join(TOADDRS), SUBJECT) )
        msg += term  +  "\r\n"
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.set_debuglevel(1)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(LOGIN, PASSWORD)
        server.sendmail(FROMADDR, TOADDRS, msg)
        server.quit()
email(content)
```

This program iterates through the **list** and emails each item, one at a time.

How can I have the program email an item on the list at certain times of day every week until it send all items on the list?

(I am asking this question related to this example because it is easier)

Let's say I want to email one item at a time until all items are sent. The first item at 2pm on Monday, the second item at 4pm on Monday, the third item at 7 pm on Tuesday, and the fourth item at 8pm Friday.  Then I want the program to send the next four items at those times every week until it sends all the items on the list. So I should be getting the next item on the list at those times.

I know linux has a program that can run a program at specific times, but if I use that it will send the whole list each time not the next item.

The python **`sleep()`** function will not work because the times I want it to  email are not in constant intervals.

Comment: How would you do this if you had to make a certain set of phone calls at particular times? You might keep a list on a piece of paper and set an alarm clock, checking off an item from the list when the clock rings. For your alarm clock, you have cron, and for the paper, you have a file on disk.

Comment: How does that solve this problem using python? I don't understand what you're saying. Are you saying I should just look at a piece of paper at certain times? this is an example... the answer can be used for many other tasks

Comment: I'm saying that Python is not the issue; the issue is the design you've chosen -- keeping a program in memory for days on end to do something on a sporadic schedule.

Comment: I would have this run six or seven times a day and five days a week. How do you think I go about fixing this?

Comment: Use cron to run your script and keep track of what you've already done in a file on disk.

Comment: Can you give me a link about the second part "keep track of what you've already done in a file on disk" I am new to that.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set cron to run at the times you want messages to send.

Keep a file on disk that contains the list, along with a place keeper string.

Each time the script runs, open the file, do what you need to do, write the file back out.

Answer (score 0):

a "**green**" & **resources very economic** approach ( no cron, no re-reading anything many times again )

**this is a smart-scheduling problem solution**, it leaves on your responsibility to create correct the smtp-sending handler and iterator, not repairing the code above.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import time
root = tk.Tk()
aNextSendingTIME = aFunctionToGetNextSendingTIME_asSECONDs()   # .SET <WHEN_NEXT>
root.title( time.ctime( aNextSendingTIME ) )                   # .GUI show ...
root.lower()                                                   # .GUI minimize inTaskBAR
# ---------
# SCHEDULER
# ---------
root.after( 1000 * ( aNextSendingTIME                          # .GOT <WHEN_NEXT>
                   - time.time()                               # .SUB <NOW>
                     ),                                        # .MUL asMSECs
            sendNextOneEmailFUNCTION                           # .SET HANDLER
            )
# /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ YOUR APPLICATION CODE \/\/\/\/\/\/\/\


# /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ YOUR APPLICATION CODE \/\/\/\/\/\/\/\
```

Then:

```
def sendNextOneEmailFUNCTION( ):
    # -----------------------------------------<your SMTP-handling code here>---


    # -----------------------------------------<your SMTP-handling code here>---
    # PLUS:
    # calc / set the next sending after aNextPointInTime_asMilliseconds DISTANCE
    aNextSendingTIME = aFunctionToGetNextSendingTIME_asSECONDs() # .GET <WHEN_NEXT>
    aNextPointInTime_asMilliseconds = 1000
                                    * ( aNextSendingTIME
                                      - time.time()              
                                        )
    root.title( time.ctime( aNextSendingTIME ) )               # .GUI update inTaskBAR
    # --------------
    # SCHEDULE AGAIN
    # --------------
    root.after( aNextPointInTime_asMilliseconds,               # .SET <WHEN_NEXT>
                sendNextOneEmailFUNCTION                       # .SET HANDLER
                )
    return
```

Finally, to set dates, do whatever input you prefer -- be it via a command-line <*filname*> or coded `asList = [ "2014-08-21 12:00", "2014-08-21 17:30",  ... ]`

```
def aFunctionToGetNextSendingTIME_asSECONDs():
    #
    # solve data adaptation from a selected data-source, be it <asList> or other
    #
    aNextSendingTIME_asSECONDs = ...

    return ( aNextSendingTIME_asSECONDs )
```

Comment: So where will I enter the time and day of the week and in what format?

Comment: @DeweyFinn code it as per your known logic in **`aFunctionToGetNextSendingTIME_asSECONDs()`** and return `aNumberOfSECONDs` to the caller. You will see the **`python`** process running all the week down in the Task Bar, with the next sending date/time displayed & updated on each re-sending done

Comment: How do I enter multiple days and times. Can you please do an example

Comment: @DeweyFinn With full respect, you **can re-use any example**, where a function reads from your list of dates/hours and does a `datetime.datetime()` conversion into seconds.